# Why is the private car still more popular over other forms of transport in the USA?

Tags: carbon-footprint, cars

I have heard that up to two thirds of all the oil we consume in the U.S. is burned in car engines. If you added the section of the infrastructure that directly supports transportation via internal combustion, the number might go up to 90%.

I don't know how much of that is consumed by buses, taxis, trucks, emergency vehicles, tractors, combine harvesters, etc. What I do know is this:

One Saturday morning I stepped out for some fresh air, and there was a traffic jam on my street. Where the hell were all these people going at 11 a.m. on Saturday? What important events did they have to attend, and what was so special about their destinations that apparently couldn't be reached by subway?

Which made me question further - why aren't there any major plans in place to incentivize public transport, or on the opposite end - make private cars less appealing? It is well within any government's power to tax the private automobile into the ground by raising taxes exponentially on the *private* use of fuel.

Would all these people want to drive on Saturday morning if they had to pay $20 per gallon? I doubt it. When people are inconvenienced, they look for *solutions*, and someone always finds one, especially if he or she foresees a sizeable profit that might come with it.

Another solution would be to built train and streetcar tracks. Lots and lots of them. Unemployment would cease to exist as a concept for many years to come. There would be jobs galore for everybody.

It's ironic, but the automotive industry wouldn't have to lose a dime: they would simply shift their focus on producing large electrical vehicles. The *steel* industry would have to leave China and come back to Pittsburgh: the demand would exceed supply by orders of magnitude during the first few years.

I don't know whether the system we had before was sustainable (when the streetcar accounted for 90% (!!) of all individual passenger trips), or would be more sustainable with a bit of help from modern technology, but it would certainly be more so than what we have now, right? A step in the right direction, perhaps.

And yet, there doesn't seem to be a single major politician, not a single leader of *any* country, even mentions these possibilities, ever. Why not? Do they know something we don't? Are the way things are currently somehow more sustainable?

Comment: @THelper: I'm all in favor of brevity where brevity is called for. I had to describe the problem before posing the question on the chance that the description might lead to some original replies. I did so in as few words as I could. Thoughtful answers usually come from people capable of reading more than fifty words at a time. I'm not looking to get a bunch of conspiracy theories for my pains.

Comment: The actual question asked is about what politicians know. Only the politicians in question can answer that. Speculating somewhat, I suspect the reason that politicians don't talk about moving away from cars is that people like cars, and politicians like votes.

Comment: Several countries, including the UK, have very high fuel taxes. And they also have heavy private motor traffic, and the consequential problems - just at a smaller scale than the US. But what is your actual question? Because if it's "do politicians know something that other people don't, that they're not telling?", then that's unanswerable.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: The heavy private auto traffic would indicate that the taxes aren't high enough. Quadruple them, and then quadruple them again. As for your question, we can hypothesize, at least. Pessimistically: the present population growth rates are not sustainable no matter how you scramble it, so they're putting off the end of civilization as we know it for as long as they can. Optimistically, a new energy source, perfectly clean, is just around the corner. Realistically, they're looking at the possible scenarios and have no answers as yet.

Comment: @SimonW: There's an awful lot of politicians out there, and some of them are enemies. _Somebody_ could _emphatically_ say _something_ that would then be televised - just to get the message out. As it is, everyone who thinks we have a problem - including the members of this site here - are automatically marginalized as paranoid doomsayers, and I wonder why that is. As for the voters: President Obama no longer has to worry about those, does he. Nor does former president Clinton. There are also the two Bushes and Carter. Ditto Mssrs. Blair and Sarkozy.

Comment: OK. While the conversation has been somewhat interesting, I'm voting to close as... I dunno. Too broad? Unanswerable / subjective? About politics more than sustainability? Take your pick :-) There might be some good questions buried in here along the lines of "what are the advantages or disadvantages of $specific_policy", or similar.

Comment: @SimonW: Look, sport, there are enough _mainstream_ dudes voting to close, shut down, browbeat, and otherwise oppress original thought and intellectual discourse. As a member of _this_ forum, do you really want to join your voice to theirs?

Comment: Finally, an upvote. What took you guys so long, I wonder.

Comment: Actually, there is one country that does this. Singapore. They tax new cars at a rate of about 150%.

Answer (score 5):

> It is well within any government's power to tax the private automobile into the ground by raising taxes exponentially on the private use of fuel.

(...)

> Not a single major politician, not a single leader of any country, even mentions this possibility, like, ever. Why not?

The answer is simple: because the majority of voters drive private automobiles and would decline to vote such politicians into power.

Also, arguably the problem is not that people are driving, but that they are all driving in the same place.  That means we should be taxing access to the *road*, not access to the car at all¹.  The environmental cost of driving 5 km in New York City is higher than the cost of driving 50 km in rural Wyoming, where public transport or cycling alternatives are unlikely to emerge.  Taxing the car overall will just increase the imbalance between urban and rural areas.

According to some, it is going to get worse rather than better with the self-driving car.  You may want to read [this blog post](http://humantransit.org/2015/11/self-driving-cars-a-coming-congestion-disaster.html).  We're not pricing roads according to demand, therefore, there are traffic jams:

> It's also why in the old Soviet Union, people spent hours waiting to buy bread: Soviet price controls made the price too low to compensate the suppliers, so there wasn't enough bread, so everyone waited in line.  Congestion — waiting in line to use an underpriced road — works the same way.

Untaxed roads are essentially communist.  (<sub>Take that, Tea Party!</sub>)

(See also: [London congestion charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_congestion_charge))

---

¹Depending on what you want to achieve.  Battle congestion: tax the road.  Give a strong incentive to move electric cars: tax unsustainable fuels, such as through a [carbon tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_tax).

Comment: I would agree with you; I would also add that there hasn't been an industry on earth more vigorously subsidized than the auto industry: a major component of their product, the roads, is manufactured for them at the taxpayer's expense; however, let me point out to you that people do lie to get ahead, and sometimes, albeit rarely, they get ahead by lying in order to do the right thing. What could possibly stop a governor, a senator, or even the current President (with no more election campaigns to run) from at least _mentioning_ the problem? It's just odd, you know.

Comment: @Ricky Congestion charges, which is essentially what is needed, are occasionally mentioned.  Private toll roads do exist, but AFAIK not in residential streets.  Arguably we need a highly dynamic street-level pricing system which prices access to streets based on current demand.  If the last 2 km cost 20$ people may decide to park 2 km away and walk the rest.  It would require some more technology than we currently have, though.

Comment: The obsession of fairly reasonable people with cars stems, I'm afraid, from the past centuries' rags-to-riches idea that one is not truly an important person unless he or she owns a horse-and-buggy. It's just a silly fetish, a habit far easier to kick than smoking. The war on tobacco in the U.S. (and the rest of the world too, I believe) has been somewhat successful. It started when the majority of voters were smokers.

Comment: @Ricky For urban areas, I don't disagree with you, although in North America, many cities are extremely poorly designed on the *assumption* that people have a car — those are essentially failed cities.  In rural and remote areas, a car might make the difference of travelling 3 hours or 3 days to get to a city (or if it exits, waiting for a bus that might go at most once a day, forcing one to spend the night in that city).

Comment: Some of those failed cities can be redesigned. Paris was once, and is no worse for it. Unsustainable cities should contract or be allowed to fail. ... People choose to live in rural areas or urban areas. As for the holiday trip to the shopping district with the obligatory visit of the opera house: when there's a demand, supply isn't far behind. Trains, light rail, trolleybuses - there's always something. Rumor has it that with the exception of a forty-mile stretch in Upstate New York, one could get from Main to Michigan by streetcar until Robert Moses and GM came and ripped out the tracks.